# How does the "lazy evaluation" of Boost Log's trivial loggers work?

Tags: c++, boost, lazy-evaluation, boost-log

[*Follows up [Check boost::log filter explicitly?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50345102/9305398)*
]

The following example uses the trivial logger from [Boost Log](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/master/libs/log/doc/html/index.html). It outputs `1`, showing that `expensive()` is only called once. How does it work? Why is `expensive()` not called?

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa0a761fa43b0119)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/log/expressions.hpp>
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>

int count = 0;

int expensive()
{
    return ++count;
}

int main()
{
    boost::log::core::get()->set_filter(
        boost::log::trivial::severity >= boost::log::trivial::warning
    );

    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(error) << expensive();
    BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << expensive();

    std::cout << count << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[2018-05-21 14:33:47.327507] [0x00007eff37aa1740] [error]   1
1
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It works by using a bit of macro/preprocessor magic. The statements look indeed like a function call to some `operator<<()`:

```
BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(warning) << expensive();
```

However, simplifying a lot, the macro works as if we had written something like:

```
if (level == warning)
    logger << expensive();
```

If you wanted to simplify that code to avoid writing all the time, you could define a macro like this:

```
#define LOG_WARNING if (level == warning) logger
```

And then we could use it as:

```
LOG_WARNING << expensive();
```

---

The actual [`BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL`](https://github.com/boostorg/log/blob/boost-1.67.0/include/boost/log/trivial.hpp#L112) macro ends up expanding into:

```
for (
    ::boost::log::record _boost_log_record_N =
        (::boost::log::trivial::logger::get()).open_record(
            (::boost::log::keywords::severity = ::boost::log::trivial::error)
        )
    ;
    !!_boost_log_record_N;
)
    ::boost::log::aux::make_record_pump(
        (::boost::log::trivial::logger::get()),
        _boost_log_record_N
    ).stream() << expensive();
```

As you see, depending on the `!!_boost_log_record_N` loop condition (which in turn depends on the result of `open_record()`), the body of the loop will be run zero or more times; which is the reason why `expensive()` is not always run.

Comment: I love that they called that macro `BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL` (also love that you did what [I never get around to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344063/check-boostlog-filter-explicitly/50345102#comment87707289_50345102))

Comment: Note that conditional execution of the streaming expression is deliberate and documented, for example in [Tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial/trivial_filtering.html).

Comment: @AndreySemashev: Indeed -- this question was written to clarify how it worked [due to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344063/check-boostlog-filter-explicitly). Didn't mean it wasn't intended -- actually, I expect logging libraries to support something similar (otherwise having to write explicit conditions to avoid potentially expensive operations becomes very tedious). Thanks for writing such a useful library!